# Is React's setState asynchronous or something?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, state, synchronous

Hmm. I'm using `setState` and for some reason the code following it doesn't have access to the new state!

What gives?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeap. It's asynchronous. I'm posting this because this isn't really immediately obvious to new React users.

React "queues" updates to a component's state.

If you need to execute a code block that's dependent on the new state change, pass a callback like so:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    isFinalCountdown: false,
  }
}

//blablabla

//then somewhere you got...
this.setState(
  {isFinalCountdown: true},
  function () {//<--- whoa. this solves your all your synchrosity woes!
    console.log(this.state.isFinalCountdown); //true!
  }
);

console.log(this.state.isFinalCountdown); //false!
```

All of this is in the docs, it's just something that really needs to be reiterated to avoid those common bugs that new React users likely come across.

Check it out: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Out of interest, what's the use case here? You already know what the new state is because you set it, so what's the use in accessing it via `this.state`?

Comment: You're right. `setState` is pretty fast so for most cases you don't need to use the optional callback thingy. You can expect that "state" will be current in `render`. However, it's a different story if you use `setState` in some specialized component method and need to access that updated state immediately. You won't see it, and need to use the callback thingy.

Comment: Ain't there a way to trigger the callback only if anything changed within state?

Comment: This was great.  I was filtering data based on state change, but it wasn't taking until I used the callback, and respond to David, yes I knew the new state, but with a number of different filters it got very messy trying to pass a bunch of parameters instead of using state.