# react js adding object to state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Testing some things in React js and having some issues with some of my logic. I am trying to get value from inputs in a form then on submitting that form i want to take that object of input values and add them to my ctcList array. I am trying to use the es6 features of spread for concating my current newCtc state with my ctcList state. When i console log i get the newCtc values but then the ctcList array is empty. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import TestData from './TestData';


class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      test1:'',
      test2:'',
      newCtc:{},
      ctcList:[],
      arr: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{
      const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      const data = await result.json()
      this.setState({arr:data})

    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


  onChangeInput = (e)=>{
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  newSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();



    this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.newCtc,{test1:this.state.test1, test2:this.state.test2}));


    console.log(this.state.newCtc)

    this.addContact();



    this.clearInput();
    console.log(this.state.newCtc);

    }



    addContact = ()=>{
      this.setState({ ctcList:[ ...this.state.ctcList, this.state.newCtc] });
      console.log(this.state.ctcList);
    };




    clearInput = ()=>{
      this.setState({test1:'',test2:''});
      this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.newCtc,{test1:'', test2:''}));
    };

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
      <Contact firstName = {this.state.name} lastName='mcdaniel' phoneNumber = '585-721-3824' />
      <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {this.onChangeInput}></input>

      <TestData data={this.state.arr} />  


      <form onSubmit = {this.newSubmit}>

      <input type='text' name={'test1'} value={this.state.test1} onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <input type='text' name={'test2'} value={this.state.test2}  onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <button type='submit'> submit </button>
      </form>

    </div> 
    )
  }
}
export default ContactList;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is React's setState asynchronous or something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820583/is-reacts-setstate-asynchronous-or-something)

Comment: So one thing I did find was adding a call back to setstate but for some reason that’s not working for me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one, take notice on the callback function of setState

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      test1:'',
      test2:'',
      newCtc:{},
      ctcList:[],
      arr: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{
      const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      const data = await result.json()
      this.setState({arr:data})

    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


  onChangeInput = (e)=>{
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  newSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.newCtc,{test1:this.state.test1, test2:this.state.test2}), ()=>{
        console.log('newctc', this.state.newCtc)
        this.addContact();            
    });

    }



    addContact = ()=>{
        let newCtcList = [...this.state.ctcList];
        newCtcList.push({...this.state.newCtc});
        console.log('newctc addcontact', this.state.newCtc);
        console.log('newctclist',newCtcList);

      this.setState({ ctcList: newCtcList }, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state.ctcList);
        this.clearInput();
      });

    };




    clearInput = ()=>{
      this.setState({test1:'',test2:''});
      this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.newCtc,{test1:'', test2:''}));
    };

  render() {


    return (
      <div>

      <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {this.onChangeInput}></input>



      <form onSubmit = {this.newSubmit}>

      <input type='text' name={'test1'} value={this.state.test1} onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <input type='text' name={'test2'} value={this.state.test2}  onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <button type='submit'> submit </button>
      </form>

    </div> 
    )
  }
}
export default ContactList;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a problematic line

```
// newCtc is empty => so Object.assign, simply returns {test1: 'some value', test2: //  somevalue }
// this.setState then merges this into the array, so newCtc is not actually updated
// but the properties test1 and test2
this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.newCtc,{test1:this.state.test1, test2:this.state.test2}));
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Contact from './Contact';
import TestData from './TestData';


class ContactList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      test1:'',
      test2:'',
      newCtc:{},
      ctcList:[],
      arr: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{
      const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      const data = await result.json()
      this.setState({arr:data})

    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }


  onChangeInput = (e)=>{
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  newSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const ctcCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.newCtc);

    this.setState({newCtc: Object.assign(ctcCopy, {
      test1: this.state.test1,
      test2: this.state.test2,
    })})


    console.log(this.state.newCtc)

    this.addContact();



    this.clearInput();
    console.log(this.state.newCtc);

    }


    // I would also copy this.state.newCtc
    addContact = ()=>{
      this.setState({ ctcList:[ ...this.state.ctcList, ...this.state.newCtc] });
      console.log(this.state.ctcList);
    };




    clearInput = ()=>{
      this.setState({test1:'',test2:''});
      const ctcCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.newCtc);

      this.setState({newCtc: Object.assign(ctcCopy, {
        test1: this.state.test1,
        test2: this.state.test2,
      })})
    };

  render() {


    return (
      <div>
      <Contact firstName = {this.state.name} lastName='mcdaniel' phoneNumber = '585-721-3824' />
      <input type = 'text' name = 'name' onChange = {this.onChangeInput}></input>

      <TestData data={this.state.arr} />  


      <form onSubmit = {this.newSubmit}>

      <input type='text' name={'test1'} value={this.state.test1} onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <input type='text' name={'test2'} value={this.state.test2}  onChange = {this.onChangeInput}

        />
      <button type='submit'> submit </button>
      </form>

    </div> 
    )
  }
}
export default ContactList;
```